# PHP not working inside page on Amazon EC2 server with nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I've used [this tutorial](http://codingsteps.com/install-php-fpm-nginx-mysql-on-ec2-with-amazon-linux-ami/) to set up a simple webserver on Amazon EC2, with PHP, mySQL, nginx and php-fpm. Everything seems to be up and running, html pages are opening just fine. My phpinfo() works fine as well, showing Server API as FPM/FastCGI and php-fpm as active. So far so good.

I now copied one of my old websites, which uses php and is working fine on my old server (which runs Apache without php-fpm by the way), to the new server and opened the index.php page. It opens, displays fine, but the Twitter login button to continue into the application shows this link:

```
<? echo $content;?>
```

Instead of showing "redirect.php" as it does on the live website. So somehow it seems as if the php within the page is not working. With a clean nginx error.log, reloading this page generates the following output in the log:

```
2016/10/29 12:32:58 [error] 2936#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_45g3uvcilj8913naoa1nrenfn3, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/html/*****/index.php on line 2
PHP message: PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /var/www/html/*****/index.php on line 6
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: access_token in /var/www/html/*****/index.php on line 15" while reading response header from upstream, client: *****, server: *****, request: "GET /tlm/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "*****"
```

I'm guessing that the permission denied error may be the cause, but I'm having a hard time figuring out why. Especially since the phpinfo() file works just fine. As you can probably tell, I'm a novice when it comes to these things.

Something about my config: the user in nginx.conf is set to nginx, and /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf contains at least the following:

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0664
user = nginx
group = nginx
```

So, I'm not even really sure I have a question that's more specific than "Why doesn't this page work?" But I hope that someone is able to help anyway.

I've seen plenty of similar questions, sometimes not having an +x on some of the folders leading up to the webserver content being the problem, but I've verified and world has +x on every folder leading up to my webserver folder so that shouldn't be the problem.

Anyone who might be able to point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your patience :)

Comment: Does **PHP** on new EC2 server have **short tags** enabled. If not enable it and check.

Comment: `chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www`

Comment: In the `nginx.conf` you should have: `user nginx;`

Comment: Thanks @Haridarshan, that was it indeed! Short tags were off, I enabled those and then it took me some time to figure out that I also needed to restart php-fpm, not just nginx. Doh. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your new installation of php does not allow the short tag http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag